# It appears I've run out of 32-bit address space. What are my options?

Tags: python, numpy, bigdata

I'm trying to take the covariance of a large matrix using `numpy.cov`. I get the following error:

```
Python(22498,0xa02e3720) malloc: *** mmap(size=1340379136) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Process Python bus error
```

It seems that this is not uncommon for 32-bit machines/builds (I have a 64-bit mac os x 10.5, but using a 32-bit python and numpy build as I had trouble building numpy+scipy+matplotlib on a 64-bit installation).

So at this point what would be the recommended course of action that will allow me to proceed with the analysis, if not switching machines (none others are available to me at the moment)? Export to fortran/C? Is there a simple(r) solution? Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Are you trying to map over 4GiB of data?

Comment: 64 bit is the option, but is your problem even tractable at that size. Dense covariance matrices of that size suggest operations that run forever! You might find the 64 bit build of R is stable on Mac.

Comment: Whoops, I guess not. `sys.getsizeof(x)` gives me only 60 bytes. My array is 15000 x 4 though, and I did not have `rowvar=False` as was intended (the input is transposed with respect to R's convention). Perhaps this was the error... with the matrix transposed, it works. But is indeed strange.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for the 64-bit Mac -- I tend to think R is worse with memory management (which is why I switched to Python for this project at one point) but I completely forgot about the 64-bit advantage.

Comment: R is not worse or better at the memory management.  These are all shipped out to BLAS or optimized BLAS implementations.  In my case, I simply use memory mapped files, and have easily produced and stored 20k x 20k covariance matrices.  It's not that big a deal to handle the data in slices...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be at your place, I would try to "pickle" (save) the matrix on my hard drive, close python , then in command line re-open the pickeled file and do my computation on a "fresh python" instance.

I would do that because maybe your problem is before computing the covariance.

```
import cPickle
import numpy
M = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]]) # here it will be your matrix
cPickle( M , open( "~/M.pic", "w") ) # here it's where you pickle the file
```

Here you close python.  Your file should be saved in you home directory as "M.pic".

```
import cPickle
import numpy
M = cPickle.load( open( "~/M.pic", "r") )
M = numpy.coa( M )
```

If it still does not work, try setting a "good" dtype for your data.  numpy seams to use dtype 'float64' of 'int64' by default.  This is huge and if you do not need this precision, you might want to reduce it to 'int32' or 'float32'.

```
import numpy
M = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]] , dtype.float32 )
```

Indeed, I can guarantee you that C/Fortran is not an option for you.  Numpy is already written in C/Fortran and probably by people cleverer than you and me ;)

By curiosity, how big is your matrix?  how big is your pickled file?

Comment: The matrix which I am using to take the covariance matrix is only 60MB, but since it was 1500x4 and with `rowvar=True` it was trying to create at 1500x1500 matrix, which I guess was the problem. In any case, I needed `rowvar=False` to get what I wanted...

Comment: but still an interesting problem though; I thought about exporting the table to a file and then calculating the elements of the covariance matrix element-wise in Fortran, and exporting them as they are calculated so the large array would not have to be retained in memory at once (so I think this would be the advantage of doing this in Fortran directly, but I suppose I could also do that in Python then).

Comment: Stepping down the precision is also an interesting option.